# Symbols not loading from Symbol Server

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012, symbol-server

I have followed the directions and I created and loaded my symbols into my local Symbol Server path. I added the path C:\SymbolServer to the .pdb locations in VS.

[image: Symbol Server File Directory]

I also disabled Just My Code and Enabled Source Server Support. However, everytime I debug my program and look at the modules window it says it loads from the default path where the project is located.(C:\Users\mcgeedm\documents..) and I want it to load from C:\SymbolServer. I am using VS 2012.

Answer (score 1):

That behavior you are trying to get seems odd.

When you run an application from Visual Studio it automatically resolves the assembly and it's PDB files from the application directory. If it can't find it, it will try to load it from another location, which includes the symbol directory. That's just the way it works and should work in my opinion.

Comment: My goal is just to test to see if VS can grab the symbols from the symbol server. Is there a way to exclude the symbols in the application directory?

Comment: Why not remove all the PDB and related files from the executing assembly and try to attach the process instead of building and debugging the application.

Comment: I thought I have to start the application first before trying to attach it to the process? Which means I would always have to build first?

Comment: And If I don't debug am I able to see which symbols loaded?

Comment: You can also use WinDbg to debug your application without building. And you should build indeed, but remove the PDB, etc. and then run it, so it can't resolve the PDB from the build location.

Comment: Ok, I will have to view a few tutorials to learn how to use WinDbg. I disabled building in Visual Studio however, still no luck as it didnt load the pdb in the Symbol Server